# Getting Error in Cordova Installation in Windows

Tags: node.js, cordova

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g cordova 
<!--'npm WARN engine cordova-js@4.0.0: wanted {"node":"~0.10.x"}
     (current: {"node":" 0.12.7","npm":"2.11.3"})' 
    'npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} 
     (current: {"node": "0.12.7","npm":"2.11.3"})'
    'npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} 
     (current: { "node":"0.12.7","npm":"2.11.3"})' 
    'npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with 
     npm@1.3.4 but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree-->
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the NodeJS you have installed is too new for xmlbuilder. You could try downgrading it to the 0.10.x series with something like

```
npm uninstall n
npm install n@0.10.32
```

and run the original command after that.